# Where to find a Katana looking item in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm looking for a Katana like wepons in The Elder Scrolls V Skyrim. I have not been able to find any or craft any so if I can let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Blades (a group that protects the Dragonborn) carry katanas, so progress the main story until you get to the hidden stronghold of The Blades to get a katana.

Link by @Kyle Rone - http://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Blades_Sword_(Skyrim)

The link states you can get one as soon as a character reveals him/herself to be a Blade and shows his/her secret room. It is near the enchanter.

Comment: heres the relevant link https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Blades_Sword_(Skyrim)

Answer (score 6):

There are several places to get a Katana in Skyrim:

- Delphines secret room on a weapons rack.
- The Sky Haven Temple containing 4 Katanas and Dragonbane.
- Bolar's Oathblade is in The Bloated Man's Grotto (If you are at any point in the quest "Ill Met By Moonlight" Bolar's Oathblade will not spawn in).
- Harkon's Sword which you get from his corpse at the end of the Dawngaurd DLC.
- Akaviri sword which can be looted from Dexicon Evicus with a high pickpocket skill.
- Fulthiem, in the Nightgate Inn a little ways away from Windhelm.
- The Ebony Blade which you can find in Dragonsreach at level 20 as a daedric quest.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main sources for the katana blades in Skyrim.  The first and easiest is the Blades and their associated locations.
The second is Bolar's Oathblade inside Bloated Man's Grotto, a little challenging at early levels as it is surrounded by many wild animals.
The third is the Akaviri sword carried by Dexion Evicus in the Dawnguard questline.  To get this one you have to have a high enough pickpocket skill and the misdirection perk.